# How to embed XBase expressions in an Xtext DSL

Tags: java, xtext

I am writing a simple little DSL for specifying constraints on messages, and Have been trying without success for a while to embed XBase expressions into the language.

The Grammar looks like this:

```
grammar org.xtext.businessrules.BusinessRules with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase
//import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xbase" as xbase
import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/common/JavaVMTypes" as jvmTypes
generate businessRules "http://www.xtext.org/businessrules/BusinessRules"

Start:
    rules+=Constraint*;

Constraint:
    {Constraint}
    'FOR' 'PAYLOAD' payload=PAYLOAD 'ELEMENT' element=ID 'CONSTRAINED BY' constraint=XExpression;



PAYLOAD:
    "SimulationSessionEvents"
    |"stacons"
    |"any"
;



Range:
    'above' min=INT ('below' max=INT)?
    |'below' max=INT ('above' min=INT)?
;
```

When trying to parse a file such as:

FOR PAYLOAD SimulationSessionEvents ELEMENT matrix CONSTRAINED BY ...

I can't get it to work for  ... = any kind of Arithmetic expression, although it works for ...= loop or if expression, or even just a number. As soon as I do something like '-5' or '4-5' it says `Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement '-'`, even though the Xbase.xtext Grammar looks like it allows these expressions.

I don't think I'm missing any Jars, as it doesn't complain when I run the mwe workflow, but only when trying to parse the input file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

edit:
The buildpath for the project is the following:

```
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.xtext_2.2.1.v201112130541.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.7.0.v20120127-1122.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.7.0.v20120127-1122.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.common_2.7.0.v20120127-1122.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.xtext.util_2.2.1.v201112130541.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\com.google.guava_10.0.1.1.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\com.google.inject_3.0.0.no_aop.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\javax.inject_1.0.0.v20091030.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.antlr.runtime_3.2.0.v201101311130.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core_1.2.1.v201112070431.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.commons.cli_1.2.0.v201105210650.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime_2.2.0.v201112070431.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils_1.2.1.v201112070431.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.xtext.xbase_2.2.1.v201112130541.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.xtext.common.types_2.2.1.v201112130541.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.log4j_1.2.15.v201012070815.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.commons.logging_1.0.4.v201101211617.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.xtext.generator_2.2.1.v201112130541.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.xtend_1.1.0.v201108020519.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.icu_4.4.2.v20110823.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.xpand_1.1.0.v201108020519.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.xtend.typesystem.emf_1.0.1.v201108020519.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore_2.7.0.v20120130-0943.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.codegen_2.6.0.v20120130-0943.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\de.itemis.xtext.antlr_2.0.0.v201108011202.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.antlr.generator_3.2.0.v201108011202.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib_2.2.0.v201112070431.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib_2.2.1.v201112130541.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.xtend2.lib_2.2.1.v201112130541.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch_2.2.0.v201112071250.jar
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language_2.2.0.v201112071250.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed,  it turns out you need to include the xbase.lib jar on the build path of the project that actually declares models of your DSL.

Comment: "Project that actually declares models of your DSL" means the project that uses you DSL? So the project that has the *.mydsl files?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the Xtend library on the classpath of the project that contains the DSL file.

Select 'Build Path' from the context menu and choose 'Add libraries'. Pick the Xtend library and it should work for you.

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I have edited the question to include all the libraries on the Xtext project's build path, it look like the Xtend one is there

Comment: Also by DSL file I assume you mean the .xtext file, as opposed to the files in which I actually have models of my DSL(*.brules)? So you are referring to the Xtext project folder

Comment: Sebastian thanks for your help, it turns out it needs the xbase.lib jar on the build path, see my answer below

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant with "project that contains DSL file". Terminology is not a simple thing :)